# Create a search method with AND/OR options in Linq and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying  to create some methode  for searching and filtring data  in  databese  using  c#  and asp.net mvc 4  (linq)

```
public ActionResult Search_Names_Using_Location(string b,string d, int c=0,int Id=0)
{
    ViewBag.Locations = db.Locations.ToList();
    var agentlocation = new AgentLocationViewModel();
    agentlocation.agents = new List<Agent>();          

    agentlocation.agents = (from a in db.Agents
                            where a.LocationId == Id
                            && (a.LocationName == b)
                            && (a.age > c )
                            select a).ToList();

    return View(agentlocation);
}
```

The  problem  is  that  user  can  let  some  texboxes  empty, so the   value  of   Id  or  a   or    b    can  be  null     so   the  query   will  get  nothing.

Is  their  any  suggestions   to  do  that   (i  can  go  with  if  else  but  that's  hard  if  i  have  7  or  8  strings)?

Comment: Some ideas here: you can do a SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM...) - nested selects where each one handles a constraints. This is like handling AND statements. Of course you wouldn't add the constraint if there was no value. In the case of an OR you could do a UNION. I am assuming your source is SQL here (so not using Linq)

Comment: Do you need to AND all your conditions? If the record in database does not have location/Id/Age then should the record be added to result?

Comment: Also, why would you operate on data in your business logic? You should do all the filtering in your database with queries so that you get the desired output in C#. This will be much faster and a better approach.

Comment: @PiyushParashar  what  i need  is  to  search  records  from  database    if  the  user  tipe  all  string their  will  be  AND   if   he  let  some  textbox  empty,  i  want  that  this clause will be skipped like it never was there

Comment: @PiyushParashar While I completely agree with not performing business logic in the ActionResult, I disagree with filtering "in the db".  This is perfectly valid linq and it will filter on the db side before returning.

Comment: @PiyushParashar   it's  just  a   get  method  so  i  dont  need  to   do  filttering  in  my database

Comment: @DavidL   (y)  .............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for `null` inside query

```
public ActionResult Search_Names_Using_Location(string b,string d,
            int c=0,int Id=0,)
    {
        ViewBag.Locations = db.Locations.ToList();
        var agentlocation = new AgentLocationViewModel();

        agentlocation.agents = new List<Agent>();

        var noId = string.IsNullOrWhitespace(Id);
        var noB = string.IsNullOrWhitespace(b);
            agentlocation.agents = (from a in db.Agents
                                    where (noId  || a.LocationId == Id)
                                    && (noB  || a.LocationName == b)
                                    && (a.age > c )
                                    select a).ToList();



        return View(agentlocation);
    }
```

Comment: and  what  i  will get  if  it's  a  null  value?

Comment: @saidmohamed11 if it's null, then this clause will be skipped like it never was there

Comment: This does not make sense. If the location and Id are empty you will return all the records which match age value whereas you were looking for something with Id and location.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted.  Boolean logic checking for null indeed would seem to be the only way to handle multiple potential filters without isolating separate queries before this point.  +1 from me.

Comment: @PiyushParashar the TS wants to skip the clause if the values are not entered and this piece of code will solve the problem.

Comment: i  get  this  error  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsNullOrWhiteSpace(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: @saidmohamed11 I've updated the code, forgot that those 'stringIsNull*' methods don't map to SQL methods

Answer (score 1):

If you have AND conditions only you can use

```
var query = db.Agents;

if (Id != 0) 
{ 
   query = query.Where(x => x.LocationId == Id)
}

if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(b))
{
   query = query.Where(x => x.LocationName == b)
}
...
```

var result = query.ToList(); // actual DB call

This will remove useless `empty` conditions, like `WHERE (0 = 0 OR LocationId = 0)`

In case of OR conditions and combinations you can take a look at [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)
So you can use Or and And predicate combinations like this:

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```